# Django Create Multiple Objects (Same Model) From One Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have been researching this issue for a couple days now with no luck.  Hoping someone out there can help.

Let's say we have the following models:

```
User model (django.contrib.auth.models)

class Children(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The goal:  When a new user wants to create an account, they will fill out the User form and be able to add x amount of children to their account.  Essentially, the template will have a user form, and x amount of children forms (depending on how many children the user has) all bundled under the same < form > tag.

I used this reference when creating the view: https://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/

The view looks like it should work.  My problem is with the template.  The trick is that I am not sure how many children each new user will have so I can't hardcode the children form.  Does anyone know what a template would like look for this issue or how I can accomplish my goal?

Comment: You are looking for formsets, in particular [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). Get it working for a fixed number of children first, then you can use Javascript to add child forms dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

*I know it is a little late to answer this but i found this unanswered and i thought i could contribute*
There can be multiple solutions to this.
I can mention one which i believe will suit your need.

```
<!--This is the form for parents and Javascript inserts Dynamic Fields -->
<form id="parent_form" method="POST" action="{% url 'url_name' %}">
    <input type="text" name="parent_name">
    <input id="child_count" onchange="inject_child_details()" 
    type="number" name="number_of_children" min=0>
     <div id="child_details">
        enter code here
     </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="{{script_nonce}}">
function inject_child_details() {
  var x = document.getElementById("child_count").value;
  details_div = document.getElementById("child_details");
  details_div.innerHTML = ''

    for(var index = 1;index <= x;){
    details_div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<input type="text" name="child'+index+'name" placeholder="Name of Child '+index+'">');
    index = index +1;
    }

}
</script>
```

The HTML to insert should be in a single line or should truncate with

`'+`
and next line should start with the above inverted 
 `+'`